# initial value problem to find the function

Tags: calculus

I was given this homework problem but I wasn't in class when we went over how to do it.

> Solve the following initial value problem to find the function $y(x)$ such that
>   $$\frac{dy}{dx} = (8x+7)\sqrt{2x−3}\\y(2)=0$$

Comment: I can't quite read the equation. Is the $y$ multiplied on the right with the function in $x$ on the left? The differential equation is $$y' = ((8x+7)\sqrt{2x-3})\cdot y$$ right? With the IVP $y(2)=0$? If there is $y$ multiplied on the right, use the technique of seperation of variables. If not, use direct integration (on the right is a function solely in $x$)

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0):

You are asked to find the primitive of $x\mapsto (8x+7)\sqrt{2x-3}$ which takes the value $0$ at $x=2$.

Let $u=\sqrt{2x-3}$, then $(8x+7)\sqrt{2x-3}=(4(u^2+3)+7)u$ and $u\mathrm{d}u=\mathrm{d}x$. Therefore, one gets: $$\int(8x+7)\sqrt{2x-3}\,\mathrm{d}x=\int(4(u^2+3)+7)u^2\,\mathrm{d}x=\frac{1}{15}(2x-2)^{3/2}(24x+59)+c.$$
The initial condition gives: $$c=-\frac{214\sqrt{2}}{15}.$$